# Graph-tool/Autoconf - configure.ac:39: error: possibly undefined macro: PKG_INSTALLDIR

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, autoconf, pkg-config, graph-tool, autogen

I have been trying to compile graph-tool from source. When running `./autogen.sh` I receive the following error message:

```
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I m4' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
configure.ac:39: error: possibly undefined macro: PKG_INSTALLDIR
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
```

I have been told that this is because I am missing `pkg-config` (http://main-discussion-list-for-the-graph-tool-project.982480.n3.nabble.com/graph-triangulation-cc-55-61-fatal-error-CGAL-Periodic-3-Delaunay-triangulation-traits-3-h-No-such-fy-td4026810.html#a4026824) but `pkg-config` is already running on my machine and is of the latest version. Running `dpkg -l pkg-config` returns:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                                  Version                         Architecture                    Description
+++-=====================================================-===============================-===============================-===============================================================================================================
ii  pkg-config                                            0.26-1ubuntu4                   amd64                           manage compile and link flags for libraries
```

Does anybody know how I might be able to fix this problem or what it is being caused by? I am running Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not the only one.  It seems that the `PKG_INSTALLDIR` breaks pkg-config versions earlier than 0.27 [as experienced by someone else here](http://redmine.audacious-media-player.org/issues/248).

There doesn't seem to be a PPA for 14.04 with pkg-config > 0.26, from my brief search.  You'll probably have to build it yourself.

Comment: That is useful to know, thank you. Simply commenting out the PKG_INSTALLDIR line as suggested in the other post, alas, did not solve the problem though.